# Try Catch doesnt working when the fetch api returns a 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its basically what the title says, my template string in the URL is formatted directly with user input, and if the user inputs incorrectly, the try/catch should catch it and return a 404 and it should console log "Error" while also returning "Error" on the screen, but it doesn't, the Component passes through anyways

```
import './cssdirect/App.css';
import Daily from './components/daily';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Loading from './Loading';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function App() {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [city, setCity] = useState('Paris')
const [weatherData, setWeather] = useState([])
const [error, setError] = useState(false)

const getWeather = async() =>{
  setLoading(true)
  setError(false)
  try{
    const resp = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=imperial`)
    const pResp = await resp.json()
    setWeather(pResp)
    setLoading(false)
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log("ERRRRROOOORRRR")
    setError(true)
  }
}

const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(city) 
  getWeather()
}    

useEffect(()=>{
  getWeather()
},[])

  if(loading==true){
    
    return <>
    <h1 className='title'>Monkey Wit Da Weather</h1>
    <Loading/>
   
  }
  else if(error===true){
    return<>
    <h1>Error</h1>
    </>
  }
  else{
    return<>
      <h1 className='title'>Monkey Wit Da Weather</h1>
     <Daily {...weatherData} setCity={setCity} city={city} getWeather={getWeather} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
   
     
    </>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Also, you put your API key in the original question, I suggest you delete the question (the key is going to be visible in edit history).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not an error, it will return a Promise. The Promise API proposes the following:

1. Each asynchronous task will return a promise object.
2. Each promise object will have a then function that can take two
   arguments, a success handler and an error handler.
3. The success or the error handler in the then function will be called
   only once, after the asynchronous task finishes.
4. The then function will also return a promise, to allow chaining
   multiple calls.
5. Each handler (success or error) can return a value, which will be
   passed to the next function as an argument, in the chain of
   promises.
6. If a handler returns a promise (makes another asynchronous request),
   then the next handler (success or error) will be called only after
   that request is finished.

So it will be :

```
const resp = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=imperial`).then(response => {
      console.log("response:", response)
}).catch(error => {
      console.log("error:", error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#differences_from_jquery):

> The Promise returned from `fetch()` won't reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP `404` or `500`. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

```js
fetch('https://httpstat.us/404')
  .then(function(){
    console.log('200 OK');
  }).catch(function(){
    console.console.log('404');
  })
```

Above code it won't run into catch block.

You can do something like this:

```js
class FetchError extends Error {
  constructor(response) {
    super(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    this.response = response;
  }
}

function fetchSomething(...args) {
  return fetch(...args)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new FetchError(response);
    }
    return response;
  });
}
```

You can read more here [github/fetch/issues/203](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203)